# MongoDB oplog transformation into Mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-oplog

I use the oplog in Mongoose similar to Tim Oxley's example (https://gist.github.com/timoxley/1502645).
I am looking for an efficient way to turn a newly inserted document (oplog 'i' operation) into a Mongoose document.
I tried this:
    var my_model = mongoose.model('test_doc', my_schema);
    // ...
    function oplog_receiver(op, doc) {
      if( op === 'i' ) {
        doc = new my_model(doc);
        doc.isNew = false;
      }
      // ...
      doc.modified_at = new Date();
      doc.save(err => {});
    }

That worked well.
Is this the way to go or is there a better way of doing this?

Many thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mongodump using --oplog? 
And then mongorestore using --oplogReplay?

Comment: Hello Probal,

many thanks for your feedback! As far as I can see the mongodump and mongorestore commands are more offline kind of activities. What I was looking for was a way to online capture the oplog activities and make the returned objects valid Mongoose objects.
The code pasted above works so far, I would like to know still if there is a more 'recommended' way to achieve this.

Best regards,